# Open a text file without clearing everything in it?

Tags: python, io

```
file = io.open('spam.txt', 'w')
file.write(u'Spam and eggs!\n')
file.close()

....(Somewhere else in the code)

file = io.open('spam.txt', 'w')
file.write(u'Spam and eggs!\n')
file.close()
```

I was wondering how I can keep a log.txt file that I can write to?
I want to be able to open a txt file, write to it, then be able to open it later and have the contents of the previous write still be there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change `'w'` to `'a'`, for [append mode](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open). But you really ought to just keep the file open and write to it when you need it. If you are repeating yourself, use the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

```
file = io.open('spam.txt', 'a') 
file.write(u'Spam and eggs!\n') 
file.close()
```

The w(rite) mode truncates a file, the a(ppend) mode adds to current content.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = io.open('spam.txt', 'a')
```

Use mode 'a' for Append.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open it in append mode

```
file = io.open('spam.txt', 'a')
```